Is facebook discontinued automatic fb_mobile_purchase (Purchase event) and started to log Start trial and Subscribe?

facebook-ios-sdk: 17.0.0

we have enable log in-app events automatically


We rely on the Purchase event (also known as fb_mobile_purchase) for the outcome/result to our campaigns and we noticed that the iOS SDK stopped sending Purchase and started to send Start trial & Subscribe instead. Also other internal events like fb_mobile_purchase_restored & fb_mobile_purchase_failed seem to be migrated to other events, all in the same time. I am attaching screenshots from our Events Manager.
Purchase Event stopped working and started Start trial & Subscribe
For Purchase, we also send the event from Server (blue graph line) and the yellow graph line is sent automatically from sdk.
fb_mobile_purchase_restored
fb_mobile_purchase_failed
Has anyone else noticed this problem?
We didn't try anything yet because we try to understand what happens. The modification is from facebook, we didn't push any update

We see the same behaviour... not sure what's going on. Last SDK update was 2 weeks ago, so seems like a server-side change.

I've seen this behavior on two separate apps. One (much bigger one) has fixed itself on sept. 5, whereas the issue still persists.

I've noticed two more things:

I can still see the events in "Events manage" -> "Overview"
If I go to "Data sources" -> Event -> "View detail", there is an infinite loading and some 500s in the logs. I hope it's a FB issue they fix soon.


The problem still persists but as quick fix log Purchase manually now and it seems to work.
